# BouncyCastle abbreviation UBER?

Tags: java, bouncycastle, keystore, abbreviation

what does the abbreviation UBER mean? I know that UBEr is a BouncyCastle-Keystore, etc. but i don't know what the abbreviation mean.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a reference to the German word "Über" (over *or* super) and is not an abbreviation. Per the [BoncyCastle Specifications](https://bouncycastle.org/specifications.html)

> The Bouncy Castle package has three implementation of a keystore.
>
> The first "BKS" is a keystore that will work with the keytool in the same fashion as the Sun "JKS" keystore. The keystore is resistent to tampering but not inspection.
>
> The second, **`Keystore.BouncyCastle`**, or **`Keystore.UBER`** will only work with the keytool if the password is provided on the command line, as the entire keystore is encrypted with a PBE based on SHA1 and Twofish. **`PBEWithSHAAndTwofish-CBC`**. This makes the entire keystore resistant to tampering and inspection, and forces verification. The Sun JDK provided keytool will attempt to load a keystore even if no password is given, this is impossible for this version. (One might wonder about going to all this trouble and then having the password on the command line! New keytool anyone?).